# Prove that $2\cdot \cos \frac{72}{2}\cdot \cos \frac{24}{2}+2\cdot \sin \frac{96}{2}\cdot \sin \frac{72}{2}=0.5$. Additional data added

Tags: trigonometry

To solve it I have tried some options, where in one of them I  applied product to sum formulas, which seemed to be very helpful, but didn't get the answer.
 Used these formulae: 
$$\cos(a+b)+ \cos(a-b)=2\cdot \cos(a)\cdot \cos(b)$$
$$−\cos(a+b)+\cos(a−b)=2\sin(a)\sin(b)$$
And now, I am stuck at this:
$$\cos(48)+\cos(24)-\cos(84)+\cos(12)=0.5$$
Then tried to make the arguments similar using a double angle and a half angle formulae $$2\cos^2(24)-1+\cos(24)+\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos(24)}{2}}+\cos(84)=0.5$$ Anyway, I can't show that expression above really is 0.5.

Comment: I don’t understand. Why do you write $\frac{72}2$ instead of $36$, for instance?

Comment: So was written on that sheet of paper, but I know that it is 36 :).

Comment: Do you know these formulea ? 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\cos(a+b)+\cos(a-b) = 2 \cos(a) \cos(b) \\
-\cos(a+b)+\cos(a-b) = 2 \sin(a) \sin(b)
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: No, I didn't.Thanks!

Comment: Note that if these are degrees, then the degree sign is obligatory; otherwise the unit is taken to be radians. For instance, $\sin 90^\circ = 1$, while $\sin 90 = 0.89399\ldots$. The degree sign can be typeset using `^\circ`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the angles are in degrees, the equation clearly cannot hold: all of the sines and cosines in the expression are positive.  Since sine is increasing between $0^\circ$ and $90^\circ$, we have
$$
2\sin48^\circ\sin36^\circ>2\sin45^\circ\sin30^\circ=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}>\frac{1}{2}.
$$
The entire left side is therefore greater than $0.5.$  Indeed, the value of the left side is approximately $2.4563$.

If the angles are in radians, the statement seems incredibly unlikely, and would be spectacular if true.  Alas, a numerical check shows that it isn't.

Comment: In fact, one can say that the statement with angles in radians must be false on general principles: it would imply that $\cos 12$ is algebraic. (The left side is a polynomial in $\cos 12$ using angle-sum identities.)  Then Henning Makholm's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/299140/3736) provides a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks, Will Orrick!

Answer (score 1):

*Using the formulae and supposing that you work on **degrees** :*

$$ \cos(a+b)+\cos(a−b)=2\cos(a)\cos(b)$$

$$−\cos(a+b)+\cos(a−b)=2\sin(a)\sin(b) $$

*we apply them and transform your given equation :*

$$2\cos \frac{72^\circ}{2} \cos \frac{24^\circ}{2}+2\sin \frac{96^\circ}{2} \sin \frac{72^\circ}{2}= \cos\bigg(\frac{72^\circ}{2} + \frac{24^\circ}{2}\bigg)  + \cos\bigg(\frac{72^\circ}{2} - \frac{24^\circ}{2}\bigg) + \cos\bigg(\frac{96^\circ}{2} - \frac{72^\circ}{2}\bigg) - \cos\bigg(\frac{96^\circ}{2} + \frac{72^\circ}{2}\bigg)  $$

$$=$$

$$\cos(48^\circ) + \cos(24^\circ) +  
\sin(12^\circ) - \sin(84^\circ) = \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: So how do you prove the last equality, given that none of these angles are mirrors of each other?