# rational points at rational inputs of x+ sinx

Tags: functions, recreational-mathematics

Let $f(x)=x+\sin x$

The question: Is there an $x\in Q$ for which output of the function is also rational? (Apart from the trivial case of $x=0$ where $f(0)=0$)

My attempt: Clearly the range of $f(x)$ is set of real numbers and from graph of the function it is very clear that rational outputs do come for many real numbers, but except for x$=0$ I couldn't find any other value.

Kindly help me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are many questions of this type - did you have a look already? I found [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299124/is-sinx-necessarily-irrational-where-x-is-rational) first.

Comment: Isn't this the same as asking for which rational values of $x$ the value of $\sin x$ is rational, which is well known?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is sin(x) necessarily irrational where x is rational?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299124/is-sinx-necessarily-irrational-where-x-is-rational)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sum of a rational number and a irrational number is irrational but $sin(x)$ is irrational (except 0) for all rational (also transcendental but not matter) then $x+sin(x)$ is irrational(also transcendental but not matter) for all rational

Comment: I wanted a rigorous proof on this so that it is established well beyond any doubt.

Comment: I think that my proof is perfectly rigorous

Comment: It's ok don't downvote

Comment: I don't down vote .