# Is $\sin n/\sin m$ irrational for nonzero integers $n\neq m$?

Tags: trigonometry, integers, irrational-numbers, ratio, transcendental-numbers

As shown in [Is sin(x) necessarily irrational where x is rational?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/299124/163), the sine of any rational except for zero is transcendental. But what about the ratio of two such numbers, at least for integers? I thought about expanding $\sin n$ in terms of $\sin 1$ and $\cos 1$, but maybe there's already been some prior work on this?

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: Presumably you want to rule out $n=-m$ as well.

Comment: I suspect this is open.

Comment: I do not understand the close votes on this question. Surely if asking "what is known about the independence of $\pi$ and $e$?" is on topic both here and on MO, this question is as well? What further context beyond curiosity is needed here?

Comment: How do u express the ratio?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I started with the polynomial expansion of $\sin n/\sin 1$ but didn't spot the connection in [Akiva's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4821161/163). Is that the reason the question got closed?

Comment: @JiaoCtagon What do you mean? $\frac{\sin n}{\sin m}$?

Comment: Side note: $\sin n$ and $\sin m$ are called [incommensurable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commensurability_(mathematics)) in that case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WLOG we can assume $m,n > 0$. Suppose by absurd that $q = \frac{\sin(n)}{\sin(m)}$ is rational. This would imply $q = \frac{e^{in} - e^{-in}}{e^{im} - e^{-im}}$ and hence $q(e^{im} - e^{-im}) = e^{in} - e^{-in} \Leftrightarrow q(e^{i(2m+n)} - e^{in}) = e^{i(2n+m)} - e^{im}$. So $e^i$ would be a root of $q(x^{2m+n} - x^{n}) - x^{2n+m} - x^{m}$, which can't happen because $e^i$ is trancendental by Lindemann-Weierstrass.

Comment: Short and concise, I like it - welcome to math StackExchange!

Comment: It is known that the root of a nonzero polynomial with algebraic coefficients is algebraic. Therefore, $q = \sin(n)/\sin(m)$ cannot be algebraic either.

Answer (score 14):

As shown in the answer you linked, the [Lindemann–Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) implies that $\cos 1$ is transcendental. It turns out that $\dfrac{\sin n}{\sin 1}$ is a polynomial in $\cos 1$; in particular,
$$\frac{\sin n}{\sin 1}=U_{n-1}(\cos 1)$$
where $U$ is the [Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials). Not only that, but $U_{n-1}$ has integer coefficients and has degree $n-1$.

Assume without loss of generality that $0<m<n$. Suppose $\dfrac{\sin m}{\sin n}=\dfrac ab$, with $a,b$ integers. Then dividing numerator and denominator by $\cos 1$, we see that $\dfrac{U_{m-1}(\cos 1)}{U_{n-1}(\cos 1)}=\dfrac ab$, or
$$aU_{n-1}(\cos 1)-bU_{m-1}(\cos 1)=0.$$
Since $\cos 1$ is transcendental, it is not the root of any nonzero polynomial with integer coefficients. Thus the polynomial must equal zero everywhere:
$$aU_{n-1}(x)-bU_{m-1}(x)=0.$$
But this is impossible as this polynomial has degree $n-1$ and cannot be the zero polynomial.

Comment: I think this argument can be extended to show that $\sin m/\sin n$ must be transcendental.

Comment: another way to do it is to notice that $\sin^2 Nx$ is a polynomial of degree $2N$ in $\sin x$ with rational coefficients and use this for $\sin^2 nm$ which then is a polynomial of different degrees in $\sin n, \sin m$ and then use $\sin m =q \sin n$ to obtain a nontrivial polynomial equation with rational coefficients for $\sin n$

Comment: Great, thanks! Transcendentality would be an interesting property as well 

Comment: See Timpa's answer for what I think is a cleaner argument.

Answer (score 2):

I put it as a comment, but it may be useful to add it here for reference: for every $N \ge 1$ we have that $\sin^2Nx$ is a polynomial of degree $2N$ in $\sin x$ with rational coefficients

(the squaring is needed due to the odd-even split for $N$ since if $N$ odd we have $\sin Nx$ is a polynomial of degree $N$ in $\sin x$ with rational coefficients, but for $N$ even we have that $\sin Nx =\cos x$ times a polynomial of degree $N-1$ in $\sin x$ with rational coefficients which easily follows by induction from the rule for $\sin (x+y)$, so squaring and using $\cos^2 x=1-\sin^2 x$ sidesteps that)

Then applying this to $\sin ^2 mn$ we get that is a polynomial of degree $2m$ in $\sin n$ and one of degree $2n$ in $\sin m$, both with rational coefficients, so if $\sin m =q \sin n, q \in \mathbb Q$, substituting we get that $\sin n$ is a root of a nontrivial polynomial with rational coefficients which contradicts the standard transcendence results for $\sin n, n \ge 1$.

The same argument leads to a contradiction if $q$ is algebraic since roots of polynomials with algebraic coefficients are algebraic too, so the ratio must indeed be transcendental.

Comment: can there be a step by step method

Comment: Definitely more than just a comment, thanks!